# Passing strongly-typed data from a View to a Controller

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I've got a stringly-type view defined using `@model MyNamespace.Customer` with a form created using `Html.BeginForm( "NewCustomer", "CustomerReg", FormMethod.Post )` helper.

The NewCustomer action on my CustomerRegController controller looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult NewCustomer( MyNamespace.Customer objCustomer )
```

I am "filling" from model-bound fields on the page a portion of the Customer fields.

When I submit I get into the correct action, but the objCustomer is all initial values. I though I could pass strongly-typed data that way; am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using textboxfor etc for all of your inputs?

Comment: generally yes, with a few exceptions.

Comment: to clarify, there are a few @Html.DropDownListFor or CheckBoxFor elements.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your view is strongly typed to `@model MyNamespace.Customer` doesn't mean that this model will somehow be automagically posted to your action when the form is submitted. Basically you need to have input fields for each property you want to retrieve inside your form if you want this property to be passed to your POST action.

Also make sure that this `Customer` object is a POCO with a default (parameterless) constructor where each property you would like to retrieve has public getters and setters. Otherwise the default model binder will never be able to deserialize the request to this model. The ideal solution to this problem is to use a view model which is a class that you specifically design to meet the requirements of your view and stop passing your domain models to it. This view model will of course have a default constructor and public setters and getters for all properties you would like to retrieve.

Comment: We're currently using a shared domain-model pattern for getting these POCOs across the barrier - we may move away from that to a ViewModel approach as we get a little further down the road, but for now it's an acceptable methodology for us. All properties do have public getters and setters and there is a parameterless constructor, so the class should be fully serializable.

Comment: I guess I'm still unsure if I bind a textboxfor(model => model.STreetAddress) (for example) and submit the form should be expecting that the action would receive a Customer with a StreetAddress? Or will I need to fill up a customer in my action from the Request.Form values? Or am I missing some other part of the equation? I'm pretty sure I've see strongly-typed objects as Action parameters, but I haven't done that much work in MVC yet.

Comment: No in this case the `StreetAddress` property of your model will be automatically bound. You don't need to be using `Request.Form` at all. The model binder will automatically bind request values to your model assuming the names of your input fields respect the standard naming convention.

Comment: And that's true even if I'm not filling the entire Customer model object before submitting, right? If I were just collecting the StreetAddress in this view, but not the City, then I would expect Customer.StreetAddress to be "some value" and Customer.City to be null. Wonder where I've gone wrong then.